# simpson paradox in classroom: reports?

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, statistics

he Simpson's Paradox is a statistical phenomenon in which a trend or relationship observed within a dataset disappears or reverses when the dataset is divided into smaller groups. It occurs when a confounding variable affects the relationship between the primary variables being analyzed, leading to incorrect or misleading interpretations.

i am looking for references on experiences on working with simpson paradox in classroom(basic school or undergraduate courses).